# IOS expected expression error

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to use an if-statement inside the switch but I keep getting an expected expression error. I would be grateful if anyone could help me to solve this issue.

```
switch ([ApplicationModel getApplicationType]) {
        case CSApplication: {}
            break;
        case RAApplication: 
        {
            if (indexPath.row == FloorLevelIndex || indexPath.row == RoomIndex) 
            {
                [cell setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];            
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You dont need a brace set at the beginning of the case.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: @cjrieck 
if (indexPath.row == FloorLevelIndex || indexPath.row == RoomIndex)  this one

Comment: @AnastasiaY and what are `FloorLevelIndex` and `RoomIndex`? Just `NSInteger` or something of the sort? If those are types, you won't be able to compare a number to a type. You probably want the number representation of those.

Comment: probably `FloorLevelIndex` is declared with a semi colon. make sure it is a valid constant.

Comment: @cjrieck they were just defined and it didn't work. You should add this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `FloorLevelIndex` and `RoomIndex` are types, you won't be able to compare a number to a type (hence the error). You probably want the number representation of those or define them with a `NSInteger` value

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that [ApplicationModel getApplicationType] returns the valid data type that swtich case supports.

> The variable used in a switch statement can only be integers,
>   convertable integers (byte, short, char), strings and enums

Should be like this:

```
switch ([ApplicationModel getApplicationType]) {
        case CSApplication: 
             break;

       case RAApplication: 
            if (indexPath.row == FloorLevelIndex || indexPath.row == RoomIndex) 
            {
                [cell setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];            
            }
            break;

       default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I am sure that it returns valid data.
the problem was with the defined FloorLevelIndex and RoomIndex

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this code in my Xcode and it works fine:

```
NSLayoutAttribute attr = NSLayoutAttributeLeft;
switch (attr) {
    case NSLayoutAttributeTop: {}
        break;
    case NSLayoutAttributeLeft: {
        if (YES) {
            NSLog(@"works");
        }
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

So the structure of your switch statement is correct.